# "where" generic contraint limitation?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How can I achieve what is exemplified below?

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    TRepository Create<TRepository>(DbContext context) where TRepository : IRepository<*anything derived from EntityBase*>;
}
```

I want to be able to achieve the following.

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{        
}

var repository = factory.Create<IUserRepository>(context);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another generic type and give that a type constraint:

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    TRepository Create<TRepository, TEntity>(DbContext context) 
        where TRepository : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityBase;
}
```

Comment: Any way I could avoid having to `factory.Create<IUserRepository, User>(context);` without having to specifie `User` which is implicit?

Comment: In this case no as the method parameters don't help.